# Simple form / simple fields for, limit which records are displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a model where Person has many Appointments. Person accepts nested attributes for Appointments. I want to show a form to update the Appointments a person has in a given month.

```
=simple_form_for @person do |f|
   ... person info ...
   = f.simple_fields_for :appointments do |builder|
       ... appointment fields
```

Other than specifically checking the appointment dates before displaying the fields, is there a way to limit the appointments that are returned from the database?

Comment: Could you make yourself more clear?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean...
But if you are wish to limit the number of records that are being pulled from the database all you need to do in the controller is to use the :limit option in find for example

```
MyModel.find(:all, :limit => 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= f.simple_fields_for :answers, @person.appointments.limit(1) do |a|
```

or

```
= f.simple_fields_for :answers, f.object.appointments.limit(1) do |a|
```

Based on this answer:
[Limit simple_form_for associated records number in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917565/limit-simple-form-for-associated-records-number-in-ruby-on-rails)